# Lubuntu hibernate Xfce Power Manager "not authorized"

Tags: lubuntu, hibernate, xfce4-power-manager

OS: Lubuntu 14.04
Package: Xfce Power Manager
Package Settings:
- On AC > Actions > Put the computer to sleep when inactive for: 15 Minutes
- Extended > Set computer inactivity sleep mode: Hibernate
Intent: hibernate computer after 15 minutes of inactivity
Error message: not authorized
Error time: at hibernation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Follow the instructions for Ubuntu: [How do I hibernate my computer?](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html)

That is, test first, then create a file `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla` with the following content:

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
```

Note that in order to create this file you need root permissions. So, for instance, use `sudo nano /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla`

Comment: Sorry to hear that. However, this is a different problem with hibernation. See [DebuggingKernelHibernate](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelHibernate) for how to debug this. Also, have a look whether others have had the same problem (and perhaps) already fixed for the device you are using. Eventually, you might want to report a bug against the kernel you are using. You might also want to check out [TuxOnIce](http://tuxonice.nigelcunningham.com.au/)

Comment: For anyone else who comes across this: This worked for me on Xubuntu 20.04 to get the Hibernate buttons to show up in the shutdown dialog, *but* I had to append `resume=UUID=swap-uuid-from-fstab` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default.grub` (and run `sudo update-grub`) for it to actually resume from hibernation successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem under xubuntu and it was due to light-locker which I believe is in use also under lubuntu. Reinstalling light locker fixed the problem permanently for me:

```
sudo aptitude purge light-locker light-locker-settings
sudo aptitude install light-locker light-locker-settings
```

I believe that removing and then re-installing fixed a policy problem somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

For Lubuntu 14.04.1 I find /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla where was

```
[Disable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=no

[Disable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate
ResultActive=no
```

Change ResultActive to **yes** for **both** blocks. If you don't find com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla - try to search any *.pkla file in /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority folder for some same strings

Comment: @xebeche's answer above is better, as any changes under /var/lib/polkit-1 will be overwritten whenever the policykit-desktop-privileges package is upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but just to point out something important, **be careful when reinstalling light-locker** and **light-locker-settings** because this action also removes **lubuntu-desktop*** which could be troublesome.

I would explore the polkit options first. Just chiming in.